# php alert not defined or fails to display

Tags: javascript, php, html, alert

I have made a simple form and php script which should read a variable from the html form text box and when the user clicks submit a simple message will be displayed saying 'You are searching for songs by *artist_name*' but when i try i get either a blank page or a message saying undefined. however if i just echo the php variable it displays the value correctly.

i have tried to just use

```
alert($artist_name) and alert('$artist_name')
```

But i get Uncaught ReferenceError: $artist_name is not defined. or the alert displays '$artist_name' instead of the value ?

However something like

```
<?php echo $_GET["artist"]; ?>
```

successfully get the text ???

and this works ok too.

```
elseif ($artist_name =="foo") { ?>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      alert("you enetered foo");
      window.location = 'index.html';
  </script>
<?php
}
```

so it is getting the variable ok but i just cant seem to include it in my alert message which is the entire aim of this code, Please can someone show me what i am doing wrong. Many thanks.

**my code below:**

the html

```
<form id="form1" action="searchresults.php" method="GET">
    <div id="artform">
        <fieldset>  
            <legend> Search for music </legend> 
            <p> <label> Artist (*): </label> <input type="text" name="artist" id="artist"  placeholder="enter an artists" class="add1"></p>
        </fieldset>                             
        <input type="submit" class="button1">
        <input type="reset" class="button2">
    </div>
</form>
```

the php

```
<?php
$artist_name = $_GET['artist'];

if (empty($artist_name)) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Field blank !, please try again.');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('You are searching for songs by' $artist_name); // the issue is here
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: `alert('You are searching for songs by <?=$artist_name?>');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to enclose $artist_name with PHP start and end tag.

```
alert('You are searching for songs by' $artist_name); // the issue is here
```

Should've been:

```
alert('You are searching for songs by <?php echo $artist_name; ?>'); // the issue is here
```

Comment: Important to note that the issue is, fundamentally, that he needs to echo the value of that variable as opposed to printing the variable name. The PHP tags without the echo statement wouldn't produce the desired result. Edwin, to print the "interpreted"/actual value of a variable, you need to 1) enclose the code in PHP tags as @KEK noted, and 2) "echo"/print  the value

Answer (score 0):

thank you i got it working, Kek i tried your method but i got an error uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list, But 125248 comment worked perfectly, i had to include the  tags for it to work. Thank you for your time.